# Projections over a subespace spanned by a unit vector.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $q$ be a unit vector of $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $W$ the subespace spanned by $q$.

Show that $proj_W(v) = (qq^T)v$ for every $\mathbb{R}^n \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and find the matrix of the linear transformation given by $T(proj_W(v) ) = proj_W(v) $

So for the first part I have: $proj_W(v) = \frac{q \cdot v}{q \cdot q} q = (q^Tv)q$ but I don't know would that product conmute to get the desired result.

After showing that, it would be obvious that the matrix is $qq^T$.

Comment: The product commutes because $q^Tv$ is just a $1\times 1$ matrix, i.e. a real number.